# Appending a string to the `puts` output

Tags: ruby, concatenation, puts

I am building a gem which will append a particular string to every `puts` output. A use case might look like this:

```
string_to_append = " hello world!"
puts "The web server is running on port 80"
# => The web server is running on port 80 hello world!
```

I am not sure how to do this. A pseudo-code of it might be something like this:

```
class GemName
  def append
    until 2 < 1
        if puts_is_used == true
            puts string << "hello world!"
        else
            puts ""
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Any insight into the best approach regarding how to do this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done with aliasing. I'd say that this is a very common idiom for decorating methods.

```
# "open" Kernel module, that's where the `puts` lives.
module Kernel
  # our new puts
  def puts_with_append *args
    new_args = args.map{|a| a + ' hello world'}
    puts_without_append *new_args
  end

  # back up name of old puts
  alias_method :puts_without_append, :puts

  # now set our version as new puts
  alias_method :puts, :puts_with_append
end

puts 'foo'
# >> foo hello world

# it works with multiple parameters correctly
puts 'bar', 'quux'
# >> bar hello world
# >> quux hello world
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm - thanks! I'm a little confused by the need to alias the puts_without_append (i.e. backing up the old puts). I tried the puts_with_append method w/o 'puts_without_append' (using just 'puts') just for kicks. So 'puts args.map{|a| a + ' hello world'}' instead of 'puts_without_append args.map{|a| a + ' hello world'}' but I get 'TypeError: can't convert String into Array'. Not sure why? Just curious...Thanks again!

Comment: @dougiebuckets: if you don't back up original `puts`, how will you call it with a string appended?